# Python Selenium script throws a "this.each is not a function" error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some quotes from Goodreads.

The following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://www.goodreads.com/author/quotes/7014283.G_K_Chesterton"

s=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

pages = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.u-textAlignRight a")

chesterquotes=""

for counter in range(int(pages[-2].text)):
    print(counter)
    counter += counter

    quotes = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.quoteText")

    for quote in quotes:
        chesterquotes += quote.text.split("― G.K. Chesterton")[0].split("― G. K. Chesterton")[0] +"\n"

    next_page = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.next_page"))).click()
    modal_close = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.modal_close")
    if len(modal_close):
        modal_close[0].click()
```

throws `each is not a function` error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mate.mrse\PycharmProjects\chesterquote\venv\scraper.py", line 28, in <module>
    next_page = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.next_page"))).click()
  ...
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: this.each is not a function
```

However, this works fine if I comment out this part:

```
    for quote in quotes:
        chesterquotes += quote.text.split("― G.K. Chesterton")[0].split("― G. K. Chesterton")[0] +"\n"
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: It's probably due to Chrome, according to other people who get this error. Which version are you using ? Try downgrading and rerunning.

Comment: .split() twice>?

Comment: Good Reads pages seem to not be dynamic. Why not use beautiful soup instead of selenium?

Comment: ^Set the value and than next_page.click() on the next line also.

Comment: Are you logging into GoodReads and processing the data or are you doing without logging in? For I see that after a couple of attempts, GoodReads is asking for the login (a modal pops up blocking the parent content), and hence the next page is not clicking. This is what I could trace out when I ran your code. Error occurs at this line: `next_page = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.next_page"))).click()` , and it is not clicking because of the login modal window

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using BeautifulSoup for scraping static webpages.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

if __name__ == "__main__":
  pattern = r'“(.+?)”'
  url = "https://www.goodreads.com/author/quotes/7014283.G_K_Chesterton"
  res = requests.get(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
  quotes = [re.search(pattern, quote.text.strip()).group() for quote in soup.select(".quotes .quoteText")]
  print(quotes)
```

That is pretty much all the code you need. I added the regex, so that it would remove the `- G.K. Chesterton` part at the end.